# How to restrict data changes of a variable in multiple variables which using the same data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-scope

I am facing an issue with object property changes in angular JS.

For example I have an array of objects.

```
$scope.ex1 = [{"name":"Ethel Price","gender":"female","company":"Enersol"},
{"name":"Claudine Neal","gender":"female","company":"Sealoud"},
{"name":"Beryl Rice","gender":"female","company":"Velity"},
{"name":"Wilder Gonzales","gender":"male","company":"Geekko"},
{"name":"Georgina Schultz","gender":"female","company":"Suretech"},
{"name":"Carroll Buchanan","gender":"male","company":"Ecosys"},
{"name":"Valarie Atkinson","gender":"female","company":"Hopeli"},
{"name":"Schroeder Mathews","gender":"male","company":"Polarium"},
{"name":"Lynda Mendoza","gender":"female","company":"Dogspa"},
{"name":"Sarah Massey","gender":"female","company":"Bisba"}]
```

I have a form where I show the data in a list format to display it am using angular-datatable.

When a user clicks on list items am storing that particular object in an array.

For example the user selects two items from the above list am keeping that two objects in other variable like below:

```
$scope.selected = [{"name":"Lynda Mendoza","gender":"female","company":"Dogspa"},
{"name":"Sarah Massey","gender":"female","company":"Bisba"}];
```

The issue is when I change some properties in `$scope.selected` the changes are reflecting automatically in `$scope.ex1` object.

Like below:

```
$scope.selected[0].name = "Rakesh rekala"
```

The above change will reflect in `$scope.ex1` array to that particular item.

How to restrict this scenario is there any way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript objects are mutable, use  [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to deep copy your source object array to a variable and then use the variable to push objects into the selected array

Comment: is there any way to make the javascript objects immutable, like using immutable JS or any other suitable choice for angular.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `push` line.

```
$scope.selected.push($scope.ex1[0]);
$scope.selected[0].name = "Test"; //ex1 will change

$scope.selected.push(angular.copy($scope.ex1[1]));
$scope.selected[1].name = "Test2"; //It's ok!
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ms403Ly8/124/

Comment: it works fine, and even the @shintu-joseph point is also referring to same because Javascript objects are mutable.